# Verify that a word exists in a list of Context

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, n-gram

i have a function that divide a phrase into contexts with a window(length of how to divide it) 
example : it was the best of times it was the worst of times
we find 10 contexts
so this my the result

[image: the results of my function]

my code

```
text = 'it was the best of times it was the worst of times '
#text1='c etait le meilleur des temps'
phrase = text.split()

def PhraseToContexts(phrase, window):     
      return [phrase[i:i+window] for i in range(len(phrase)-(window-1))]
print(PhraseToContexts(phrase, 3))
```

PS: i'm using python (spyder)

now, what i want is to create another function named oneContext(listContexts,phrase,word,window) that verify if this word exist in the list of contexts and return a vector contain the value 1 to say the word exists in context, 0 else.

in the same previous example
if we search about "it"
the vector that we obtain is 
[1.0.0.0.0.0.1.0.0.0]

[image]

Comment: Your contexts are of type `list` of size 3, so do you only want to check for the word at the 0 index or do you want to check for any index?

Comment: yes size 3. and no i want to check if for example "it" exist in the whole contexts list and return the vector of it  as i said in the description . like this

Comment: @SirinàStrong why you deleted your new question ? I've been working on it ! are you were expecting output such as https://paste.centos.org/view/f492d452

Comment: @SirinàStrong anyway here's the csv file as per your question. http://www.sharecsv.com/s/130443bc6a7cff6af435b81c582f47b6/6006c7e1.csv and here's the code to achieve the goal https://bpaste.net/show/YP7FY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def oneContext(listContexts,phrase,word): 
    l = [1 if word in x[int(len(x)/2)] else 0 for x in listContexts]
    return l
```

where,

```
listContexts = PhraseToContexts(phrase, window)
```

Comment: sorry i forget to say that the word need to be in the middle to be verified (1). if it's not in the middle it's (0 )

Comment: if you want to check, the word appear in the middle of the list, then in that case two cases arise: 1) in case length of list is even, 2) in case length of list is odd. In first case you can get the middle value of the list but in second case two values appear in the middle of the list. You can replace :  "word in x" with "word in x[int(len(x)/2]"

Comment: I have updated the code. Look if it fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203332/discussion-between-sirina-strong-and-mr-stark).